# Help Finding a butterfly handlebars with 23.8mm grip diameter

Tags: handlebars

I would like to mount the end bar shifters on a butterfly handlebar on my touring bike, the problem is that I can't find a butterfly handlebar with 23.8mm grip diameter, which is needed to install the shifter bar end, usually drop bars have that diameter, does anyone know where to find what I need, thanks!

Comment: Bar end shifters go inside the bars - so the internal diameter is what matters here.  Or do your shifters clamp over the outside of the bars ?

Comment: Yes i mean internal diameter sorry

Comment: @Criggie Internal diameter is what's in question ultimately, but bar end shifters need the kind of ID number offered by road bars with 23.8 OD.